# PHP Time Specific action with Amazon RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an issue with Amazon RDS Mysql instance which timezone is pecific EU-WEST-1 (Ireland) with an EC2 instance on the same network and i am trying to build an application in PHP with multi language support and multi-timezone support. For example:

i have a DATETIME field for subscribers creation in MYSQL
when i display that entry in the view it is 2 hours behind.

I have tried DateTime function in PHP to determine/pre-set the default timezone of some user to se if the time(s) displayed in the view are changing acordingly to the user's timezone, but unfortunately nothing worked for me!

Can anyone point me in the right direction or with a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: All Amazon RDS DB instances use UTC/GMT time by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to store and use dates and times in UTC, then render the local time zone to your users based on their user preferences or geo location.

RDS will be using UTC by default, even if it is in the EU-WEST-1 region.

Comment: Thank you! your anwser helped me and resolved my problem! Thanks again